# Enabling laravel 4 route to read slug instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following route in laravel.

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@profile')->where('id', '[0-9A-Za-z\-]+');
```

If `id` corresponds to id in a database, ex: `site.com/23` then I am able to fetch results from database with that specific id. However, if I want to fetch something like a title slug ex: `site.com/this-is-title` then it won't work at all. I have no idea how to tell laravel to query based on anything other than an database `id`.

My controller is:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController{
        public function profile($company_slug){
        $result = Clients::all($company_slug); 
        return View::make("home.profiles", compact("result"));
    }
}
```

Here is my template.

```
@extends("layouts.master")

@section("main-content")
<?php
   {{ $result->company_slug }}
?>

@stop
```

There is no output. If I do `<?php var_dump($result) ?>` I get `NULL`.

But as I said, if I pass an id `site.com/32` then I get result from database a for that id.

Answer (score 3):

You might use the route models:

**Solution 1:**

```
Route::bind('profiles', function($value) 
{
    $records = Profiles::where('company_slug', $value)->all();

    if ( ! $records->count())
    {
        App::abort(404);
    }
    else 
    {
        return $records;
    }
});

Route::get('{profiles}', 'HomeController@profile');

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function profile($profiles)
    {
        return View::make("home.profiles")->with('profiles', $profiles);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'HomeController@profile');

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function profile($slug)
    {
        return View::make("home.profiles")
            ->with('profiles', Profiles::where('company_slug', $slug)->all());
    }
}
```

Docu is available [here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: How do I simply check if slug exits in database inside my profiles action ?

Comment: You have to use your own model name. I have just assumed that you have named your model like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
class HomeController extends BaseController{
    public function profile($company_slug){
        $result = Clients::where('company_slaug', '=', $company_slug)->get();
        if (empty($result)) {
            //not found
        }
        return View::make("home.profiles", compact("result"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This method worked. By I am getting an object inside my template. `profiles.blade.php` if I do `var_dump($result)` why does it return an eloquent object? I just want to fetch rows like `{{ $result->title}}` any ideas how to achieve that?